# Como obtener el registro de llamadas solo siempre de los últimos 7 días

Tags: android, date

he conseguido una función que rescata el historial de llamadas sin problema alguno. Pero necesito conseguir que el historial sea de la ultima semana, osea 7 días antes desde el momento que yo consulto. No he encontrado muchos ejemplos al respecto, cualquier idea es bien recibida.Acá va mi código:

```
    private void Cargando_llamadas() {

    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int name_count = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String name = managedCursor.getString(name_count);
        String fecha = (String) DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yy k:mm",managedCursor.getLong(date));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String patron = "%s segundos";
        String resultado = String.format(patron,callDuration);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "Saliente";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "Entrante";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "Perdida";
                break;
        }


    } 
     managedCursor.close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar `managedQuery` es un metodo deprecado, en su lugar utiliza `getContentResolver().query(...)`.

Para obtener los ultimos 7 dias tienes que hacer una validacion con la columna `CallLog.Calls.DATE` diciendole que el valor sea mayor a los ultimos 7 dias, el valor de comparacion tiene que ser en milisegundos.

```
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?", new String[] { dateValidacion.toString()}, null);
```

Tomar en cuenta que `dateValidacion` es una variable de tipo `Date` que hace referencia a la fecha de hace 7 dias.

Un metodo para obtener los milisegundos de la fecha 7 dias atras a partir de este momento es el siguiente metodo

```
 public static Long getMilisegundosFechaAtras(int diasAtras) {
    Date date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (diasAtras * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // diasAtras * 24horas * 60minutos * 60segundos * 1000
    return date.getTime();
}
```

Utilizando este metodo la implementacion final para obtener el listado de llamado de los ultimos 7 dias quedaria de la siguiente forma

```
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                                                        null,
                                                        CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?",
                                                        new String[]{getMilisegundosFechaAtras(7).toString()},
                                                        null);
```

Comment: Si!! funcionó sin problemas!, muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Luego de lograr esto, como seria si yo quisiera filtrar por algun nombre en especifico? por ejemplo en este caso me convendría mucho poder filtrar por "cached name", se puede? o la unica manera de filtrar es por medio de una db?